# XAML Element Across Multiple Pages in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I'm having trouble coming up with an accurate title of what I'm trying to do, so bear with me!

I have a C# WPF application that contains a window, and the window hosts 5+ pages. I have a hardware status that is updated behind the scenes that happens independent of the current page, but if something happens the user needs to be given a status. I'd like to display a status consistently across all of my pages.

Is there any way to do this without copy and pasting a XAML element on to each of them, and then maintaining which page I'm on? My concern is regarding non-redundant UI/XAML code, not so much the status tracking.